# Django Page not found using complete url

Tags: python, django, view, http-status-code-404

im new at Django and im trying to write a very simple app, however i got stuck and have a couple of questions:

First my app is called "empleados" (spanish) and I am trying to create a simple index view which shows all the entries from my table, i can access the webpage via localhost:8000/empleados, but i cannot access the webpage via localhost:8000/empleados/index.html it is not supposed to be the same?

My current folder tree is like this:

```
 project_root/
  empleados/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    templates/
      empleados/
        index.html
        add_checklist.html

  project/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
```

My project/urls.py is like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'femsa.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^empleados/', include('empleados.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

And empleados/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.add_checklist, name='add_checklist'),
]
```

Finally my empleados/views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Empleado
from empleados.forms import *
def index(request):
    empleado_list = Empleado.objects.all()
    context = {'empleado_list': empleado_list}
    return render(request, 'empleados/index.html', context)
# Create your views here.

def add_checklist(request):
    # Get the context from the request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CheckListForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print (form.errors)
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = CheckListForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render_to_response('empleados/add_checklist.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

So my question is how access index.html with the complete url, and add_checklist.html, everytime i try to access them i just got the 404 error, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The point of routing is to have readable URLs without the need to give the exact name of the file accessed. I've never had this requirement before, so I'm not sure what the best practice for this problem is, but I suppose you could achieve that by specifying the routes in your "empleados.urls" like ``r'^index.html$'``. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's not how you do routing. For a start, you can't have two URLs with the exact same pattern. And URLs point to views, not templates.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments, i know it is not a convention anymore but i was just trying some thing with the frameworks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some other frameworks/servers, django does not serve files automatically. You must specify explicitly what to serve.

In your case, adding `index.html` to `url` will do the trick:

```
url(r'^index.html$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^new$', views.add_checklist, name='add_checklist'),
```

I must add that using `index.html` is an abandoned convention. Django allows to design urls structure in a much better fashion. Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments, i know it is not a convention anymore but i was just trying some thing with the frameworks!